# Unauthenticated OAuth passport laravel

Tags: php, laravel

on my server, `OAuth` and `OpenSSL` is installed. but when I want to send a request to server I got this error message:

```
{
    "error": "Unauthenticated."
}
```

on my localhost, everything works fine.

my codes:

routes/api.php

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['auth:api']], function(){
 Route::get('/init/','API\User\UsersController@init');
```

my laravel version is 5.5.

the result of `phpinfo();`
http://dev.randani.com/

where is my wrong?

Comment: How are you providing the access token, and are you using Apache?

Comment: I use this `$user->createToken('User App')->accessToken` for generate access token. I have a question why it works properly in localhost? but when I host the project on the server it doesn't work?